# How can I compile bitcoin on debian 7.x Wheezy? Missing libmemenv.a

Tags: linux, compiling, bitcoin-qt-setup

In the bitcoin leveldb branch, the file libmemenv.a is missing. Because the debian leveldb package does not include it, bitcoin will not compile on debian systems.

Is there any workaround? Will you all be including this library in an upcoming release?

Answer (score 1):

As per: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=270852.380

Try:

`make -f makefile.unix "USE_UPNP=-"`

UPNP is not enabled by default anyway, so compiling without it shouldn't be a problem for normal operation.